# Why I didn't get half of a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

It says in the faq:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Then why I did not get half of bounty for this question:
[How to use Callback function to get language in Tizen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048463/how-to-use-callback-function-to-get-language-in-tizen/12158935#12158935)

I need to mention that the author accepted the answer and then declined it; might have something to do with that.

Comment: Hm. The only answer was posted after the bounty started, it got two upvotes during the bounty period (the last one being 21 minutes before the end, at 12:03 and the bounty ending at 12:24). It should have been rewarded.

Comment: Perhaps the awarding script is run in batches, and you need to give it a little more time?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - since the bounty message is updated, I doubt it.

Comment: @Gnoupi I would read the FAQ in the same manner :)

Comment: @Gnoupi: Why can't the bounty message be automated on page load, separately from awarding the bounty? It's only been a few minutes past the end of the grace period, give it some time.

Comment: It *could* be that the accepting, unaccepting, accepting, unaccepting toggling has thrown things off. If you don't get the half-bounty award in the next 24 hours, flag it for moderator attention, pointing to the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12048463/timeline) perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - actually, I don't know, I'm not really knowledgeable in this area. It could, I guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok I will do that !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a matter of time, half of the bounty is now attributed.

> **Bounty Ended** with 25 reputation awarded by Community♦ occurred 14 mins ago (2012-08-31 13:30:08Z)

The script checking the criteria for the bounty doesn't execute right away, but at set times. Apparently, it happened a little more than one hour later.

---

Extract from the FAQ: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty
>   starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be
>   automatically awarded half the bounty amount.(...)

So apparently, it can take up to 24 hours

Answer (score 4):

did you receive the 2 upvotes after the 7 days + grace period or before?

Comment: Before, see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12048463/timeline

Comment: Before, the grace period ended a few minutes ago

Comment: If it just ended a few minutes ago, give it some more time. Badges usually take a while to appear (sometimes a few minutes, sometimes a few hours) because the scripts that check for the criteria run at set times.

Comment: @Jim Ok, didn't know that,